# Difficulty Creating New Directory for Upload in PHP

Tags: php, directory, hosting, chmod, mkdir

I am using PHP to create a directory.  After the directory is created it is given a chmod of 777.  I then have a simple script for a user to upload a file to the directory.  The issue that I am having is that the directory will not complete the file transfer when I run the script.  BUT... if I manually go in via FTP and create a new directory and assign 777 to the generated folder then the script works fine and the file is transferred.  Is there some set-up with my web host that is limiting this ability?  Or is it in the PHP script?  Here is the code wherein I create the new directory:

```
<?php

$thisdir = getcwd(); 
$new_dir = 'test';
$full_dir = $thisdir . "/" . $new_dir;

function chk_dir($full_dir) {
if(is_dir($full_dir)) {
    echo 'the directory already exists';
} else {
    return mkdir($full_dir);
}

}
chk_dir($full_dir);
chmod($full_dir, 0777);
?>
```

I know there must be a simple explanation for this, thank you for reviewing my issue.

Comment: In theory if the directory is created by PHP then it will have permissions to write into that directory, as it will have ownership. There shouldn't be a need to set permissions at all.

Comment: @Tak I tried taking out the chmod call and the permissions get set to "rwxr-xr-x."  Also, the files do not complete the upload.

Comment: I know this has to do with the new host I am using.  I have tested the same script on a different hosting platform and it works just fine.  What is the question that I should ask them about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if **Safe_mode** is turn on on your server.

mkdir() creates folder as owner, it's not the script owner, so the scripts couldn't upload the file into that folder. While safe_mode is turned on chmod() dosen't work.
Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php

try adding this line at the beginning of the php script to check for warnings:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: Great thanks!  I will investigate and see if that is the case.